# 'too many output arguments' error when passing function to another function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, error-handling, functional-programming

I have some error handling code that I want a bunch of functions to use, so in order to avoid repetition I thought I would put it in my generic class that holds utility functions `FunctionContainer`.

Here's a truncated version of `FunctionContainer`:

```
classdef FunctionContainer
methods (Static)
    
    function run(func, ExpInfo, logdir, newdir, varargin)
        try 
            func(ExpInfo, newdir, varargin)
        catch ME
            FunctionContainer.errproc(logdir, newdir, ME)
        end
    end
    
    function errproc(logdir, newLogDir, ME) 
        errdir = fullfile(logdir, 'error');
        movefile(newLogDir, errdir);
        pathParts = strsplit(newLogDir, filesep);
        logID = pathParts(end);
        newLogText = fullfile(errdir, logID, 'error.txt');
        fid = fopen(newLogText, 'wt');
        fprintf(fid, '%s\n%s\n', ME.identifier, ME.message);
        for i = 1:length(ME.stack)
            fprintf(fid, '%i\t%s\n', ME.stack(i).line, ...
                ME.stack(i).file);
        end
        fclose(fid);
        rethrow(ME);
    end
  
    function newdir = prolog(logdir, id, supfiles)
        id = join([id, string(clock)], '_');
        newdir = fullfile(logdir, id); mkdir(newdir)
        stack = dbstack('-completenames');
        files = horzcat({stack.file}, supfiles);
        for i = 1:numel(files)
            copyfile(files{i}, newdir)
        end    
    end
end
```

end

Here's the context in which I'm using it:

```
function realign(ExpInfo)

    fc = FunctionContainer;
    logdir = ExpInfo.logdir;
    ws = fullfile(logdir, 'workspace.mat'); save(ws);
    newdir = fc.prolog(logdir, 'realign', {ws});

    fc.run(runRealign, ExpInfo, logdir, newdir);

    function runRealign(ExpInfo, newdir)
         % do a bunch of stuff
    end
end
```

The relevant line in my script `ks_main.m` that calls `realign` is

`realign(FullData)`

I get this error:

```
8   fc.run(runRealign, ExpInfo, logdir, newdir);
Error using realign/runRealign
Too many output arguments.

Error in realign (line 8)
fc.run(runRealign, ExpInfo, logdir, newdir);

Error in ks_main (line 35)
realign(FullData)
```

I just don't understand this error in this context.  None of these functions is returning anything or has any outputs.  I could maybe understand if runRealign were getting too many inputs, and I tried defining `runRealign` like this

`function runRealign(ExpInfo, newdir, varargin)`

but that made no difference.  Maybe this has something to do with passing a function as an argument to another function?  What's the right way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `@` symbol in front of your function argument in `fc.run`. Always do this when passing a function handle as an argument (https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-a-function-to-another-function.html). Line 8 of realing.m should be:

```
fc.run(@runRealign, ExpInfo, logdir, newdir);
```

There are a couple of other issues. One is that you are missing an `end` at the end of `FunctionContainer`. This is probably just a typo in your question or else you would also have an error related to this.

Another small implementation detail is that you don't need to use `logdir` as an argument if it is going to be a field in `ExpInfo` anyway---you can simply access it from `ExpInfo` inside of `FunctionContainer` without having to pass it explicitly to `run`. Passing both `ExpInfo` and its field `logdir` to the same function is unclear and stylistically bad practice. (Which reminds me, you should provide a definition of `FullData` in your question as well. I had to discern that it requires this field.)

However, this is code as is is also going to cause an exception to be thrown on line 6 of `FunctionContainer`. The definition of `runRealign` only takes 2 arguments, but when you `try` to run it in `FunctionContainer` you expect 3: `func(ExpInfo, newdir, varargin)`.  If I change line  6 of `FunctionContainer` to:

```
func(ExpInfo, newdir)
```

it works.

To make this robust and error free you need either to parse the `varargin` in `FunctionContainer` so that it intelligently handles a variable number of arguments (https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html), or else guarantee that the input function handle points to one that has 2 arguments for ever and always.

Comment: Thanks!  I had already changed the input parameters for `runRealign` and for a second was confused until I looked at my own question.  As for `logdir` sometimes it won't be the same as ExpInfo.logdir.  I'm sure there's a way I could make this clearer/set it up better.  Given that this code in an ideal world would be run once I'm trying to balance between improving it and making it clear and moving on.  It's most important to me to have a crystal clear record of what happened, which is what all this infrastructure is about.